# use case - actor relations

Tags: uml, actor, use-case-diagram

[image]I have the below question:

An actor is associated to a use case A, which has an extension use case B and B is extension of use case C.
Question: does it mean that the actor has access to use case C?

Thanks in advance!
Joanna

Comment: hi jimmy, I do not get how you answers the above stated question. Could you give a specific answer?

Comment: I've added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed the diagram you have provided, your answer would be no, unless I am missing something where you are generalising the role of the fitment manager.

This would mean that the fitment manager would then inherit the roles of the other actor in the system.

Your diagram does not show this, so no the fitment manager does not have access to use case c. Although there is an extension to use case b  from the fitment managers interaction with use case a.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does!